# Run SonarQube plugin on Visual Studio Code on GNU/Linux

Tags: sonarqube, visual-studio-code, sonarlint

I was having some problem running SonarQube plugin and SonarLint on Visual Studio Code.
After installing the former or both plugins, I tried to run (following the tutorial...) the command `SonarQube Inject: Create global config with credentials to servers` which ended up with the following message `command 'sonarqube-inject.analyzeProject' not found`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is coming from the plugin binary not being executable by default (at least on my Ubuntu 16.04 / VSCode 1.14).
I just needed to make it executable:

```
cd ~/.vscode/extensions/silverbulleters.sonarqube-inject-1.3.0/tools/sonarlint-cli/bin/
chmod u+x sonarlint
```

Then, restart VSCode and run the command `SonarQube Inject: Create global config with credentials to servers` again and setup servers.

Comment: I tested new dev from Nikita Grizlov that he made some after I submitted this issue, and new version (before he publishes it to the market) is working fine and fixes this problem.

Comment: Any info on how to run the command from Windows ? The `SonarQube Inject: Analyze current project` is not recognized : `SonarQube : command not found`

Answer (score 2):

On windows type: Ctrl-Shift-P and then write Sonar. The editor will show the options to use.

[image]